# Solr: No Groups returned when Matches = 1 and NGroups = 1

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I am querying solr and results are grouped. Everything is working fine until I make a specific query which returns (supposedly) only 1 result. Debugging shows that there was a match and a ngroup, but no groups are returned from solr. Any pointers to the solution would be appreciated.

[image: Solr Grouping Error Description]

Comment: Do you get the single hit if you don't enable grouping? Are you querying a single server, or are there multiple nodes involved?

Comment: Without grouping I receive one hit (NumFound = 1) but results are still empty. It's a single Solr Server. No filters applied.

Comment: Have you tried applying the query directly in the admin interface, so that you can see the actual response from the server? Saying that its returning one document, but actually not returning anything indicates something might be off (maybe an empty-ish document?)

Comment: The results are correct on the Solr Admin. It shows the 1 result.
I examined the call made by SolrNet by using Fiddler and copying the http call and pasting into the browser. There's something wrong wiht the http call by SolrNet. It doesn't return the matched item for some reason but shows NumFound = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part in paging. The calculated value was start = 1, so it skipped the first result. Fixed.